Euler E152: "Analysin enim ineptam existimat"
I am trying to read Euler's "De Numeris Amicabilibus" (to
disambiguiate I mean the paper with Ennestrom number 152: he
wrote three papers with this name).
http://eulerarchive.maa.org/backup/E152.html
The sentence which has given me the most trouble is this, on the
first page, paragraph 2.
"Stifelius, qui primus huiusmodi numerorum mentionem fecit, casu
hos duos numeros 220 et 284 contemplatus ad hanc speculationem
deductus videtur; analysin enim ineptam existimat, cuius ope
plura istiusmodi numerorum paria inveniantur."
The context is this: 220 and 284 are "amicable numbers" (the
aliquot sum (sum of proper divisors) of either one equals the other) and Euler
believes that Michael Stifel (author of the Arithmetica Integra
(1544)) was the first to mention this concept (of course it was
known to the neo-Pythagoreans much earlier and studied in great
detail by Thabit Ibn Qurra and others around the tenth century, but I digress). My translation
so far begins:
"Stifel, who first made mention of such numbers, noticing these
two numbers 220 and 284 by chance, seems to have been led to
this speculation;"
However, "ineptam existimat" is causing me trouble.
I believe (maybe this is my mistake) that "analysin ... cuius
ope plura istiusmodi numerorum paria inveniantur" is a single
idea: "analysis by means of which more such pairs of numbers are
found". Moreover, "analysin" is in the accusative, so it's the
object of "existimat". But did Stifel:

consider such analysis to be silly?

consider such analysis to be inept (i.e. unable to produce more
pairs)?

Or is Stifel not the subject at all, and I should be parsing
this as something like "one considers analysis (at the time
of Stifel) to be insufficiently developed"?


I looked at Stifel's Arithmetica Integra
https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_fndPsRv08R0C/page/n41
to see what he says. The only relevant passage I could find was in the
section "De numeris perfectis", specifically on "double page
spread 11" (p.41 of the version on the Internet Archive). First,
he defines perfect numbers (i.e. the sum of proper divisors
equals the number itself) and then says:
"Hac ratione imperfecti sunt, qui ex collectione suarum partium
aliquotarum omnium, vel plus faciunt (ut 220 facit collectione
suarum partium 284) vel minus faciunt, ut 284 facit collectione
suarum partium 220."
i.e. he points out that if you're not perfect the the aliquot sum is either bigger or smaller than what you started with, and he gives the examples of 220 and 284 for these two cases. He then goes on to explain Euclid's method for finding perfect
numbers and says (about perfect numbers):
"Mira admodum sunt perfectorum numerorum rationes. Quamvis enim
parvum usum habeant numeri perfecti, in rebus Arithmeticis,
iucundum tamen est cernere, ut sub tam mira raritate eorum inter
numeros alios, proferri tamen possint seu inveniri tam prompte,
et modo tam facili, ordineque tam pulchro."
Rough translation:
"Calculations of perfect numbers are really miraculous. Although
indeed perfect numbers have little use in matters of arithmetic,
it is pleasing all the same to see (given how rare they are
amongst other numbers) they can nonetheless be produced or found
so readily and in a manner so simple, orderly and beautiful."
Perhaps there is more in Stifel's book, but I didn't find it. So Stifel doesn't actually seem to mention what he thinks about the analysis by which more such pairs could be found.
So my question is: given this, how should I translate "analysin
ineptam existimat..."?

I think the remaining text of the scholion gives some further context for the meaning of inepta. Here are some relevant parts of the "history" he is trying to tell:

Cartesius vero analysin ad hoc negotium accomodare est conatus, regulamque tradidit, qua tria talium numerorum paria elicuit [?], neque praeter ea Schotenius, qui multum in hac investigatione desudasse videtur, plura cruere [?] valuit.

I'm unsure of the transcriptions of two words above, but here's a translation based on the likely meanings:

But Descartes tried to adapt analysis to this task, and he passed down a rule by which he drew out three pairs of such numbers. Schottenius, who seems to have toiled much in this investigation, was unable to add more beyond these [pairs].

There are some key words that make it clear that inepta describes Schottenius's view:

The "enim" indicates that this view explains what precedes and is evidently contrasted with casu, i.e. "He found them by chance, since he didn't think analysis (the best tool) was apt for the job."
The "vero" after Cartesius indicates a contrast: "Descartes, on the other hand, did try to adapt analysis, and it worked out better for him...."

I don't think we can adjudicate between your first and second options solely based on syntax or vocabulary: Does Stifelius consider analysis inept for any job, or just for this job? The fact that Descartes is contrasted with Stifelius because he (Descartes) tried to "adapt analysis to this task" perhaps suggests the latter, but it may well be that Stifelius was convinced that analysis couldn't be adapted to any task.
I leave that determination to mathematical historians, since I'm out of my depth on that question.

Inspired by brianpck's suggestion to look for more context, I
looked at the 1656 book by van Schooten (Schotenius)
"Exercitationum Mathematicarum". On p.419, he says
"Sunt qui existimant, plures operationes arithmeticas reperiri,
quae algebrae non subjiciantur, inter quos est Arithmeticus haud
ignobilis Michael Stifelius"
"There are those who think more arithmetical operations are to
be found which are not subject to algebra, amongst them is the
by-no-means-unknown arithmetician Michael Stifel."
He goes on to give a quotation from Stifel's commentary to the
1553 edition of Rudolff's "Die Coss" to support this (i.e. not
the Arithmetica Integra where I was originally looking!). The
original is in German, but Van Schooten provides a Latin
translation:
"At licet resolutio aequationis cuiusque gradus ineffabilem usum
habeat expediendi quemlibet artificiosum calulum, nihilominus
tamen multae egregia supputationes reperiunter, quae algebra non
sunt obnoxiae, sed citra eam ex theorica fluunt, quod multis
utique elegantibus exemplis demonstrate possem, nisi id uno aut
altero exemplo ostendisse sufficeret"
and he goes on immediately to give the example of looking for
amicable numbers. Here is Stifel's original: https://ds.ub.uni-bielefeld.de/viewer/image/2014414/495/
